# Sorting files by time created

Tags: windows-8.1, window

My wife and I work as wedding photographers. It would be massively helpful if I could sort photographs by time taken. I know I can sort them by date but if I could sort them by time too, it would allow us to get them into a logical order fairly simply instead of having to do it manually. We use professional Canon cameras which store not only the date but time taken in the metadata.

Comment: are you saying the "Date Taken" item in the column sort, in details view  does not have the time on it also?

Comment: Sorry just noticed that it does. I guess the problem that we have been experiencing is that I collate the couple of thousand files into a single directory but have not checked that all the camera times are synced. Will Windows sort on date first then time? That is really what I want.

Comment: it seems to, then you can switch to thumbs and it seems to still use that method for sort. But i am on win7 , sooo i cant be sure it works the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand since, as @Psycogeek says, Windows Explorer has this already. All you need to do is right-click on the headings and select Date Taken, you can then sort on it, it includes the time.

Of course, given the number of pictures we tend to take with virtually unlimited storage, I find that clashing file names is a much bigger issue so I rename all my images with the Date, time and camera name, something like:

```
2013-10-05 10-37-19-NIKON D90.jpg
```

Now it will always sort in date/time order.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. I think I have my head around it now. I just needed someone to spell it out to me. The biggest practical issue is synchronising four cameras. Thank you. Jerry

Comment: I agree, you have to remember to update their times before a shoot unless they have GPS built in. Multi-cameras is why I include the camera type in the name though not helpful if you have several of the same type! Of course, even to the second, I can get a name clash so my rename workflow adds a trailing unique letter in that case. Used to use a custom script, now using AdvancedRenamer on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still out there but now successfully back from the wedding with a thousand photos to sort. I synchronised the time on all 4 cameras that we used and have managed to sort them on date and time taken in Windows Explorer. So far so good. Hugely helpful to see them in the order in which they were taken as the day's events unfolded.

However, I now need to use them in other programs to make custom DVDs or musical presentations etc and of course these programs do not see them in order by time or date and offer me no opportunity to sort them by those factors. I need to rename them sequentially so they appear in the right order but unless I can find a program that can allow me to sort them by date and time BEFORE I rename them, I can't see how I can do it? Any advice learned ones?
Many thanks, Jerry

Comment: Sorted! Windows 8.1 lets me do it automatically by pressing f2and putting in a new filename. It then increments numerically for all other selected files. Brilliant!

Comment: It looks like you accidentally created two user names, which will hamper your ability to edit your own posts.  See this to get the accounts merged: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts.  That said, this answer is really commentary on your question.  It doesn't add anything but if it goes anywhere, it should be in the question.  However, your comment looks like an actual answer.  Can you edit the answer, replace everything with your comment, and then accept your own answer?  That will indicate that the problem is solved.